# With a z-index of -1, the after pseudo element is hidden behind background

Tags: html, css

I made a simple progress bar for an online form. It worked fine, until I added a background color on the containing `div`. It seems that when `z-index` is set to -1, it hides behind the background of the parent's parent's parent.

The following JS Fiddle shows the error above what is expected.
https://jsfiddle.net/h2e52oux/

What can I do to make the top one work the same as the bottom when there is a background color?

```css
div {
  height: 100px;
}
div.bg {
  background-color: white;
}
ul {
  counter-reset: step;
}
li {
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 25%;
  text-align: center;
  font-style: italic;
  color: #999;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}
li::before {
  content: counter(step);
  counter-increment: step;
  width: 1.5em;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  color: #999;
  margin: 0 auto 5px auto;
}
li:not(:first-child)::after {
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 3px;
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0.5em;
  left: -50%;
  z-index: -1;
}
li.active {
  color: #222;
  font-style: normal;
}
li.active::before,
li.active::after {
  background: #b05d68;
  color: white;
  border: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg">
  <ul>
    <li class="active">One</li>
    <li class="active">Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
    <li>Four</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div>
  <ul>
    <li class="active">One</li>
    <li class="active">Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
    <li>Four</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

In your case it turns out that no matter what number you give to the `z-index`, adding the lines below  are enough to do the work. I set it to the value of `-2` on purpose to make it 1 layer below `li`s but that can be changed as desired. Just the `z-index` *property* alone takes no effect because it needs to be accompanied by the `position` *property* with the *value* of anything different than the *default* `static`. Setting it to the *value* of `relative` is a logical choice since I don't want to break your layout.

```
div.bg {
  position: relative;
  z-index: -2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
div.bg {
  position: relative;
  z-index: -2;
}
```

z-index only works on positioned elements (position:absolute, position:relative, or position:fixed).

Setting the z-index to -2 means the background div will be stacked below your other content.